# Showing users input History

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I have this codes for an ATM with deposit, withdraw, balance and history option.. and now my problem is the history option.. I really don't know how to make all users input into it..
I try making one but it only shows 1 history of the last input...

```
package atm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Atm {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int choose,back;
    static double withdraw,balance,deposit,depos,post;
    static String us,username="admin",ps,password="admin";
    static int []array;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\t Welcome Visitors");
        start();
    }//end of main
    public static void hello(){
        System.out.println("\t\tHello: "+username);
        options();
    }
    public static void start(){
        try{
            System.out.println("\t Username: ");
            us=input.nextLine();
            if(us.equalsIgnoreCase(username)){
                password();
            }
            else{
                System.err.println("Incorrect Username");
                start();
            }
        }//end of try
        catch(Exception a){
            System.err.print("\t Invalid Input");
            start();
        }//end of catch(Exception a)
    }//end of  public static void start()
    public static void password(){
        System.out.println("\t Password: ");
        ps=input.nextLine();
        if(ps.equalsIgnoreCase(password)){
            hello();
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("Incorrect Password");
            password();
        }
    }
    public static void depot(){
        array=new int[1];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println("\t| Input Amount to Deposit: ");
        deposit=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println("\t| Successfully Deposited|");
        System.out.println("\t| $"+deposit+" in your account  |");
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println();
        calculateDepot(deposit);
        options();
    }//end of static void deposit();
    public static void calculateDepot(double depot){
        balance=balance+depot;
        calculateHist(deposit);
        options();
    }//end of public static void calculateDepot(double depot)
    public static void withd(){
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println("\t| Input Amount to Withdraw ");
        withdraw=input.nextDouble();
        if(withdraw>balance){
            System.out.println();
            System.err.println("\t=============================");
            System.err.println("\t| Sorry You Dont Have        |");
            System.err.println("\t| Enough Balance to Withdraw |");
            System.err.println("\t=============================");
            System.out.println();
            withd();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("\t========================");
            System.out.println("\t| Successfully Withdraw|");
            System.out.println("\t| $"+withdraw+" in your account");
            System.out.println("\t========================");
            System.out.println();
            calculateWithd(withdraw);
            options();
        }
    }//end of static void withdraw
    public static void calculateWithd(double withd){
        balance=balance-withd;
        options();
    }//end of public static void calculateWithd(double withd)
    public static void bal(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println("\t| Your Total Balance is");
        System.out.println("\t| $"+balance);
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println();
        options();
    }//end of static void balance
    public static void calculateHist(double depot){
        depos=depot;
        options();
    }
    public static void hist(){
        System.out.print("\t|"+depos);
        options();
    }//end of static void history
    public static void options(){
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        System.out.println("\t| Choose Your Option    |");
        System.out.println("\t========================");
        try{
            System.out.println("\t========================");
            System.out.println("\t|  [1] Deposit          |");
            System.out.println("\t|  [2] Withdraw         |");
            System.out.println("\t|  [3] Balance          |");
            System.out.println("\t|  [4] History          |");
            System.out.println("\t|  [5] Exit             |");
            System.out.println("\t========================");
            choose=input.nextInt();
            if(choose==1){
                depot();
            }//end of if(choose==1)
            else if(choose==2){
                if(balance==0){
                    System.err.println();
                    System.err.println("\t=============================");
                    System.err.println("\t| Sorry You Dont Have        |");
                    System.err.println("\t| Enough Balance to Withdraw |");
                    System.err.println("\t=============================");
                    System.err.println();
                    options();
                }
                else{
                withd();}
            }//end of else if(choose==2)
            else if(choose==3){
                bal();
            }//end of else if(choose==3)
            else if(choose==4){
                hist();
            }//end of else if(choose==4)
            else if(choose==5){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\t| GoodBye! Thank You |");
                System.out.println();
            }//end of else if(choose==5)
            else if(choose<=6){
                System.err.print("\t| Invalid Input |");
                options();
            }//end of else if(choose<5)
        }//end of try
        catch(Exception b){
            System.err.print("\t| Invalid Input |");
            input.nextLine();
            options();
        }//end of catch
    }//end of static void option
}//MAIN END
```

Comment: Well, a history is a *list* of previous transactions; so for starters you'll have to have a list of some sort that you can add to (hint: [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). Since you need a list of *previous transactions*, you'll need to come up with a way of storing a "transaction" in the list. What is a transaction? It's an operation (withdrawal, deposit, etc.) and an amount (and optionally a result, if you want to store that). Create a little `Transaction` class to hold info about a transaction, then you can use an `ArrayList<Transaction>`.

Comment: Also ask yourself: *When* is a transaction added to the history? It's added after a user completes one. So; each time a user completes a transaction, you can create a new `Transaction` with the info and add it to your history list.

Comment: but your "depos" is neither an array or List so what where you expecting? just use Jason C 's advice...

Comment: i guess array is my hope..thank's for replyin. :)

Comment: i was able to find my asnwer and now i have another question...how can i sort the list horizontally? cause it outputs vertically

Answer (score -1):

For history you need to keep two arrays, one for keeping last transaction type (deposit, withdrawal) that changed the balance and another for the amount of the transaction. And tha array size could be constrained by a upper limit as well (say 10). So, that means at most 10 history items you would remember. Then you need to manage the chronology (sequence) of history items within that bounded set.

Comment: Unless there's a specific requirement (e.g. a homework requirement) that explicitly prohibits the use of new classes, parallel arrays (especially in the hands of a new programmer) generally lead to messes of mistakes (e.g. out of sync) or difficulties later (e.g. sorting, or passing information around) and I would not recommend doing this or giving it as advice to a new programmer.

Comment: @JasonC Appreciate. But this is just a sequential program with no parallel component or thread, all done in sequential batch, that's what I thought.

Comment: I wasn't referring to multithreading. By "parallel arrays" I mean two (or more) arrays that must exist side-by-side (rather than a single array that holds objects with fields). By "out of sync" I meant the potential for errors that makes the arrays not line up with each other any more (e.g. adding an element to one but forgetting to add it to another). Plus, sorting is virtually impossible, and if you want to pass one of the history items to a method (perhaps you want to print it) you have to make sure that all arrays and the index are available, rather than just passing one object.